# How to limit users in login system to one vote per post?

Tags: php, sql, database

How does Facebook limit one like per person per post? I'm implementing something similar for a site but I'm not sure how to approach this correctly. Should I create a table for every single post and just have rows recording which users have voted on a particular post?

Is creating as many tables as you have posts bad? Is there a better way to do this?

A better example is how Stack Overflow keeps track of which answers and questions every user has voted on. When you go to a question you've already voted on, it shows your vote. How does it do this efficiently?

I've already tried researching this and I didn't find anything that explains a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider having a table

```
POSTS (POST_ID, POST_CONTENT, POST_AUTHOR)
```

and a table

```
POSTS_LIKES (POST_ID, LIKED_BY)
```

Yes, definitely do not have one table per post, that would be a horrible design.

Either show or don't show the like button based on whether the currently logged in user appears in the POST_LIKES table as the LIKED_BY value for the given POST_ID (should be a simple query)

Comment: To clarify the second table here, each of those columns are a foreign key, and together they can be set as the primary key, thus ensuring that a user may not vote on a single post more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Have a table for users (PK=UserId). 
Have a table for posts (PK=PostId).

Have a table for Likes (Likes.PK = FK Users.UserId and FK Posts.PostId).

When the user clicks on "like" create an entry in the Likes table. Since there's only one entry PK for Likes is PK for Users + PK for Posts, it guarantees there can only be one like per post.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `votes` table in your DB.  and make `user_id` and `post_id` combined unique index. So users won't be able to give more than one vote per post.

```
Votes
----------
int vote_id    
int user_id    
int post_id    
int vote_type_id // For example 1 = UPVOTE 2 = DOWNVOTE
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a 'theyvevoted' column to the `posts` table, and fill it with:

`' ' . $userid . ' '`

So I can do an `strstr( $post['theyvevoted'], ' ' . $userid . ' ' )` later.

More efficient than having an extra table IMO if most posts will have "votes" attached.